# Define variable based on form input in Google Apps Script (Spreadsheet)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to have a form that allows the user to input some data, that then gets stored in variables for use in other functions. Specifically, I just need them to be able to define the name of two sheets (shtName and databaseName).

I can't get the variable to work in the script though as it tells me the variables are undefined (referring to shtName & databaseName here).

I get this error: `ReferenceError: "shtName" is not defined.`

If I define shtName and databaseName outside a function, it works. So that's obviously the problem but not sure how to get around it.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm">
Name of current sheet:<br>
<input type="text" name="formshtname" >
<br><br>
Which database sheet to search in?<br>
<input type="text" name="formtagdatabase">
<br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit"
    onclick="google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
        .formSubmit(this.parentNode)" />
   <input type="button" value="Close"  onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**addTags.gs**

```
  function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Tags')
  .addItem('Setup', 'openSetup')
  .addSeparator()
  .addItem('Add tags', 'findingTags3')
  .addToUi();
 }

 function openSetup() {
  var html =   HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  .showModalDialog(html, 'To auto complete tags, fill in the form');
 }


function formSubmit(form) {
var shtName = form.formshtname;
var databaseName = form.formtagdatabase;
}

function findingTags3() {
// bunch of code

/* current spreadsheet */
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
var sht =  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(shtName)); // want this to be defined from form

/* tag database spreadsheet */
var spreadsheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxx"); 
var sht2 = spreadsheet2.getSheetByName(databaseName); // want this to be defined from form

// more code
}
```

EDIT:

Ok, one way of doing it is by adding this inside function findingtags3()

```
var shtName = Browser.inputBox("Current sheet name");
var databaseName = Browser.inputBox("Input sheet name of database you want to search");
```

I suppose that will do, but it would be nicer to have a proper setup where you enter that information and it gets stored, until you change the input.

Comment: If you want to store something checkout [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service).  Or you could also store it in a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use propertiesService to store you variable until you are ready to execute the function.

Your code will look like this:

```
function exampleSubmit(){   // this function will set a mock/default values to properties
  var form = {
    "formshtname" : "Sheet1",
    "formtagdatabase" : "Sheet4"
  }
  Logger.log(form)
  formSubmit(form)
}

function formSubmit(form) {
  var docProp = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties()
  docProp.setProperty("shtname", form.formshtname)
  docProp.setProperty("databaseName",form.formtagdatabase)
}

function findingTags3() {
// bunch of code
  var docProp = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties()
  var shtName = docProp.getProperty("shtname")
  var databaseName = docProp.getProperty("databaseName")
/* current spreadsheet */
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
var sht =  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(shtName)); // want this to be defined from form
  Logger.log(sht.getName())

/* tag database spreadsheet */
var spreadsheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxx"); 
var sht2 = spreadsheet2.getSheetByName(databaseName); // want this to be defined from form
Logger.log(sht2.getName())
// more code
}
```

This is document specific property if you want this values to be unique for each user. Use [user properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) instead.